# PHP vs NodeJS - text based RPG

Tags: php, node.js

I know this isn't a very good question to ask because people may give bias answers, but was wondering if someone could list the pros and cons of using PHP vs NodeJS as a backend language in developing the average text-based online RPG.

The RPG will store its data in a MySQL database and will have typically 10-20 players online simultaneously.

For the long-run, which language would you think is more suitable?

I have several years of experience in PHP and barely any experience in NodeJS. It seems PHP has really good synergy with MySQL but I've been really hearing good things about NodeJS. Also, what design approach should I take (i.e. MVC).

Would be great to hear from someone who has a lot of experience in both languages.

Comment: Node isn't a language. Since you're familiar with PHP and barely anything about Node, isn't the choice obvious, in your case? Since there's no mention of what the challenges of RPGs are, then the only issue I can see is how well you're able to store and fetch data from your database. PHP can't deal with MySQL any better than Node can, both use an efficient way of maintaining MySQL connections, therefore there's virtually no difference when it comes to "speaking" to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is not a language. The language is Javascript.

Both are perfectly good choices, the main difference is the asynchronous approach of everything nodejs related. This increases the performance and scalability, but it's harder to debug and uglier to write and read (Learn about the callback hell). You need to get the asynchronous concept very well if you want to have the advantages people usually credits nodejs with.

This being said, you can program asynchronously with PHP, but it's far less common.

So if you are confident with PHP, you need the results fast or don't want to experiment go with it. If you want to learn or experiment, go with Node.

If the limit is 10-20 simultaneous players the performance shouldn't be such a a problem.

About the design approach, I would leave the details for last. MVC is very common and you will probably use something like that to organize your code but the choice depends on lots of factors and you should probably think about this after having the use cases / stories of your application defined and limited.

Comment: Promises are also an alternative to reaching callback hell ;)

Comment: They are, and should be used, but they are still more complicated to write, read and interact with than plain old synchronous functions. The real cool thing will be asynchronous functions. I think they are coming in ES6.